# Hello, I want to show the padding part at the bottom of my code on the screen with a delay of 10 seconds. How can I do it?

Tags: flutter, button

I want to show the padding part at the bottom of my code on the screen with a delay of 10 seconds. How can I do it?

My Code :

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';
import 'package:flutter_clipboard_manager/flutter_clipboard_manager.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'URL Shortener',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.purple,
      ),
      home: StartPage(),
    );
  }
}

class StartPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _StartPageState createState() => _StartPageState();
}

class _StartPageState extends State<StartPage> {
  bool visibilityTag = false;
  void _changed(bool visibility, String field) {
    setState(() {
      if (field == "tag") {
        visibilityTag = visibility;
      }
    });
  }

  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _globalKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  String shortUrl = "";
  String value = "";
  String buttonText = "COPY!";
  bool isChanged = true;
  TextEditingController urlcontroller = TextEditingController();
  getData() async {
    var url = 'https://api.shrtco.de/v2/shorten?url=${urlcontroller.text}';
    var response = await http.get(url);
    var result = jsonDecode(response.body);
    if (result['ok']) {
      setState(() {
        shortUrl = result['result']['short_link'];
      });
    } else {
      print(response);
    }
  }

  copy(String url) {
    FlutterClipboardManager.copyToClipBoard(url).then((value) {});
  }

  buildRow(String data, bool original) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: original
          ? Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Text(
                data,
              ))
          : Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                Text(
                  data,
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  child: Text(buttonText),
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    primary: Colors.blue,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                    minimumSize: Size(300, 40),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    copy(shortUrl);
                    setState(() {
                      if (isChanged == true) {
                        buttonText = "COPIED!";
                      }
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          SvgPicture.asset(
            'assets/logo.svg',
          ),
          SvgPicture.asset(
            'assets/illustration.svg',
          ),
          Center(
            child: Text(
              "Let's get started!",
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20,
                  color: Color.fromRGBO(53, 50, 62, 10),
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          ),
          Center(
            child: SizedBox(
              width: 200,
              height: 60,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text(
                    "Paste your first link into the field to shorten it",
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 15,
                        color: Color.fromRGBO(76, 74, 85, 10),
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 130,
            child: Stack(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              children: [
                Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                  color: Color.fromRGBO(59, 48, 84, 1),
                  child: SvgPicture.asset(
                    'assets/shape.svg',
                    color: Color.fromRGBO(75, 63, 107, 1),
                  ),
                ),
                Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 300,
                      height: 40,
                      child: TextField(
                        onChanged: (text) {
                          value = "URL : " + text;
                        },
                        controller: urlcontroller,
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                                const Radius.circular(10.0),
                              ),
                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                width: 0,
                                style: BorderStyle.none,
                              ),
                            ),
                            fillColor: Colors.white,
                            filled: true,
                            hintText: 'Shorten a link here ...'),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 300,
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: getData,
                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                          primary: Colors.blue,
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                          minimumSize: Size(60, 40),
                        ),
                        child: Text('SHORTEN IT!'),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(13.0),
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.white,
              width: double.infinity,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  buildRow(value, true),
                  buildRow(shortUrl, false),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Hello, I want to show the padding part at the bottom of my code on the screen with a delay of 10 seconds. How can I do it?
Hello, I want to show the padding part at the bottom of my code on the screen with a delay of 10 seconds. How can I do it?
Hello, I want to show the padding part at the bottom of my code on the screen with a delay of 10 seconds. How can I do it?Hello, I want to show the padding part at the bottom of my code on the screen with a delay of 10 seconds. How can I do it?

Comment: instead of duplicating text share only related code.

Comment: You can use async help in this case. and wrap with `Visibility` widget.

Comment: i am not sure how to do it, but thank you :) @YeasinSheikh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On State create a bool like

`bool showCopyButton = false;`

Change to true at

```
   SizedBox(
                      width: 300,
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: ()async {
                          print("Button Click");
                            await getData();
                          setState(() {
                            showCopyButton = true;
                          });
                        },
                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                          primary: Colors.blue,
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                          minimumSize: Size(60, 40),
                        ),
                        child: Text('SHORTEN IT!'),
                      ),
                    ),
```

And wrap with `Visibility` Like

```dart
 Visibility(
            visible: showCopyButton,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(13.0),
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.white,
                width: double.infinity,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    buildRow("Text ", true),
                    buildRow("asdad", false),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
```

or you can just `if` like

```
  if (showCopyButton)
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(13.0),
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.white,
                width: double.infinity,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    buildRow("Text ", true),
                    buildRow("asdad", false),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

Btw you need to use await before making it true.

Comment: Glad to help you out, you can also check https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SmTCmDMi4BY

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll take  look. :)  @YeasinSheikh

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps:

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
class Screen extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _ScreenState createState() => _ScreenState();
}

class _ScreenState extends State<Screen> {
  bool _paddingVisible = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 10), () {
      // Check if mounted == true, because the screen might closed
      // before 10 seconds pass
      if (mounted) {
        // Setting padding visibility to true after 10 seconds
        setState(() {
          _paddingVisible = true;
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          // All your widgets
          // When _paddingVisible becomes true it will be displayed
          if (_paddingVisible) SizedBox(height: 10),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```